# sql gone away on insert/update only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I understand the topic of "General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away" issue has been discussed multiple times here. I have tried nearly every suggestion, yet I still get the error following 7+ hours idle connection. I have a standalone PHP script that receives messages on a queue and depending on the action it may insert one or more records in a mysql table. the puzzling part comes from the fact that the same connection does not show any errors fetching data from the database however when I try to insert a record, I get the "gone away" error! has anyone run into this before? if so, I would really appreciate any insights!

Thanks!
Sean.

Comment: so you can run as many select queries as you want, but the first `insert` kills the process? or is it "run some selects, pause 7 hours, run insert"?

Comment: it's the former. I run several selects but no error. however i get an error when I try to insert. that only occurs after 6+ hours of not executing an insert statement!.

Comment: network timeout of some sort? if the connection's idle for 6 hours, a firewall/gateway might be dropping the connection but not informing either side. so next time you hit the db, the connection's gone and you get "gone away".